# how can I access notification settings in android programmatically via intent?

Tags: java, android, notifications, settings

I want to access notification settings via intent on my application, how can I achieve this?

Check the following image

[image]

---

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
intent.putExtra("app_package", getPackageName());
intent.putExtra("app_uid", getApplicationInfo().uid);
```

this is my sample codes but it gives me different output. What I want to see is a list of application exactly on the third image.

[image]

Comment: I think this is the link you are looking for: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

Comment: I've seen this before and tried some of the intent here but I didn't achieve what I wanted. Can you help me to this? I'm the kinda new to android development so I don't exactly understand everything.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is an intent that will fit your requirements, but What I did if I were you is checked every intent action having a `NOTIFICATION` word in it's name.